# How can I copy all files in a directory matching certain extensions with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've done something like this before with batch files

```
copy "%APPPATH%\*.exe" "%APPPATH%\*.exe.deploy"
```

So I want to copy all `.exe` files to `.exe.deploy'

So if I have the following in a directory:

```
a.exe
b.exe
c.foo
d.bar
```

I want to end up with:

```
a.exe
b.exe
c.foo
d.exe
a.exe.deploy
b.exe.deploy
d.exe.deploy
```

There's got to be an elegant way of doing this.  **BONUS** I'd also be like to specify multiple extensions (*.exe, *.txt, *.blob) and do it all in one command.

Comment: *There's got to be an elegant way of doing this.* - beggars can't be choosers. `gci *.exe,*.txt | % { copy -L $_ -D ($_.name+'.deploy') }`

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit : what Powershell code did you try before asking help?

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell you'd enumerate the files you want to copy and pipe the results into the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem $env:APPPATH -Filter *.exe |
    Copy-Item -Destination { $_.FullName + '.deploy' }
```

Note that `-Filter` supports only a single string. If you want to pass multiple extensions you need to use `-Include` (but that works only in combination with `-Recurse`):

```
Get-ChildItem $env:APPPATH -Include *.exe,*.foo -Recurse |
    Copy-Item -Destination { $_.FullName + '.deploy' }
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the $_ pipe syntax.  That helps